How to add less roughness to the borders of a map than to the fill of the map
Following these questions and answers (How to shade shapes) and (Unable to replicate this ggplot2 plot), say that I get ggrough (https://xvrdm.github.io/ggrough/index.html) up and running:
#install.packages("devtools") # if you have not installed "devtools" package
#devtools::install_github("xvrdm/ggrough")

library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrough)
library(sf)

trace(ggrough:::parse_rough, edit=TRUE)
#In the popup window, paste this so that parse_rough will use parse_sf for GeomSf.
function (svg, geom) 
{
    rough_els <- list()
    if (geom %in% c("GeomCol", "GeomBar", "GeomTile", 
                    "Background")) {
        rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_rects(svg))
    }
    if (geom %in% c("GeomArea", "GeomViolin", "GeomSmooth", 
                    "Background")) {
        rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_areas(svg))
    }
    if (geom %in% c("GeomPoint", "GeomJitter", "GeomDotPlot", 
                    "Background")) {
        rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_circles(svg))
    }
    if (geom %in% c("GeomLine", "GeomSmooth", "Background")) {
        rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_lines(svg))
    }
    if (geom %in% c("Background")) {
        rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_texts(svg))
    }
    if (geom %in% c("GeomSf")) {
        rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_sf(svg))
    }
    purrr::map(rough_els, ~purrr::list_modify(.x, geom = geom))
}

#Create the function parse_sf.
parse_sf <- function (svg) {
    shape <- "path"
    keys <- NULL
    ggrough:::parse_shape(svg, shape, keys) %>% {
        purrr::map(., 
                   ~purrr::list_modify(.x, 
                                    points = .x$d, 
                                    shape = "path"
                   ))
    }
}

I then plot a county map:
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
b <- ggplot(nc) +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA))

options <- list(GeomSf=list(fill_style="hachure", 
                            angle=60,
                            angle_noise=1,
                            gap_noise=0,
                            gap=6,
                            fill_weight=2, 
                            bowing=5,
                            roughness=30))
get_rough_chart(b, options)

This produces:

If I want to 1) keep the roughness setting (of the fill) at 30 and 2) I want to display the borders (and not remove them using the lwd=0 option in geom_sf or something similar), how can I independently control the roughness of the borders? As is, the borders are out of control. I want them to have some amount of roughness so that it looks like they were hand drawn, but only a little. (If this is not possible, how can I include a border that is not affected by ggrough, while the fill is still affected?)
I tried the following:
b <- ggplot(nc) +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA), lwd=0) +
    geom_sf(fill = "transparent", color = "yellow", size = 1)   

options <- list(GeomSf=list(fill_style="hachure", 
                            angle=60,
                            angle_noise=1,
                            gap_noise=0,
                            gap=6,
                            fill_weight=2, 
                            bowing=5,
                            roughness=30),
                GeomSf=list(fill_style="hachure", 
                            angle=60,
                            angle_noise=1,
                            gap_noise=0,
                            gap=6,
                            fill_weight=2, 
                            bowing=5,
                            roughness=1))
get_rough_chart(b, options)

My hope was that if I included two GeomSf elements in the list of options, maybe the first would correspond to the first geom_sf (with no borders) and the second—--with roughness set at 1---would correspond to the second geom_sf. But this didn't work:


Have you considered using the package roughsf instead? Seems it might be better suited for your purposes.

Thank you for the comment @Kat I would love to get it figured out for ggrough, but roughsf is also a possibility. I just tried making the Germany roughsf map using nearly the exact code from https://github.com/schochastics/roughsf, with the one exception being that I changed the roughness option to 50. Interestingly, I get the exact same problem that I am getting with ggrough - that the borders also go out of control. So it would be very helpful if there were a way to independently control the roughness of the fill and the borders.

Well, that wasn't helpful! So I took another look at your question, and just for the thrill of it (based on your comment about fill and transparent) I set both color and fill to transparent....You've still got the scribbled look, but nothing exceeds the outer most borders. It's even more interesting when you remove the fill (transparent) and only assign color  to transparent. Did you already do that?

I agree that it is interesting to see what happens in the different scenarios like:
b <- ggplot(nc) +  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA))
And then this removes the borders (not sure why):
b <- ggplot(nc) +  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA), color = "transparent")
vs.
b <- ggplot(nc) +  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA), lwd=0) +   geom_sf(color = "transparent", fill = "transparent")
vs.
b <- ggplot(nc) +  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA), lwd=0) +   geom_sf(color = "transparent")
But I can't figure out how to get the scribbled shading of counties while having pretty normal looking borders.

It's cumbersome, but I have a workaround you might like. It isn't a great answer so I thought I'd ask first. If I add an answer it's highly unlikely that anyone else will attempt to answer your question. The BLUF (or the newer more trendy TLDR)  is that I create a border only and layer the ggrough graph on top of it.

That would be great!

This method uses two seperate graphs, one for application with ggrough and your customization, one that doesn't use ggrough but introduces a traditional border.
This requires 2 additional libraries. One turns ggplot2 into html. The other is used to overlay the two plots.
library(ggiraph)
library(htmltools)

Since you've a few different plots in your question, here is the exact plotting code I used. I added theme constraints. This sets the panels and text to invisible -- but doesn't remove them. This they need to be there so that the plots can be aligned.
b <- ggplot(nc) + geom_sf(color = "black") + theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_line(color = NA),  # not resized or removed! (keep spacing)
        axis.text = element_text(color = NA))

The options were not changed. I will state that I used the first variation (with only one GeomSf).
After you get_rough_chart, I've got a UDF here that modifies the panel and text fields. It appears that black is used by default and it adds the axis text back into the plot. This removes the text without compromising the spacing.
(xx <- get_rough_chart(b, options))  # from your question
fixer <- function(ggr) {          # where ggr is the ggrough graph
  nd <- lapply(1:length(ggr$x$data), function(j) {
    if(!is.null(ggr$x$data[[j]]$lengthAdjust)) { # if a text element (axis label)
      ggr$x$data[[j]]$content <- ""              # remove text, but keep spacing
      ggr$x$data[[j]]                            # return modified data element
    } else {
      ggr$x$data[[j]]                            # not text, return orig data
    }
  })
  ggr$x$data <- nd                               # add mod data to graph
  ggr                                            # return mod graph
}
xx2 <- xx %>% fixer()  # modify the plot, to hide text

Next, create the border only plot. In this plot, the theme is used to remove the white background and set the font size so it matches the defaults in ggrough.
(g2 <- ggplot(nc) +
    geom_sf(fill = "transparent", color = "black", linewidth = 2) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "transparent"), # no white background
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "transparent"),
          text = element_text(size = 9)))      # text size to match defaults in ggrough

gg <- girafe(ggobj = g2, width_svg = 7, height_svg = 5)  # h/w default w/ ggrough

Last but not least, assembly.
browsable(div( # parent div, size matches ggrough's default
  style = css(width = "960px", height = "500px", position = "relative"),
  div(xx2, style = css(display = "block")),                           # ggrough graph
  div(gg, style = css(position = "absolute", top = 0, padding.top = "54.2px", # layer behind
                      width = "610px", height = "500px", z.index = -2))
              )) # size and padding found by trial and error with defaults for graph sizes


While the above code does not have fill assigned in geom_sf, if I change that and add fill = "blue", for example, you still have the same results.

 
Here's all the code used, all together
(easier copy + paste)
# uncommented code is likely unchanged code from your question

library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrough)
library(sf)
library(htmltools)    # <- I'm new!
library(ggiraph)      # <- I'm new!

trace(ggrough:::parse_rough, edit=TRUE)
#In the popup window, paste this so that parse_rough will use parse_sf for GeomSf.
function (svg, geom) 
{
  rough_els <- list()
  if (geom %in% c("GeomCol", "GeomBar", "GeomTile", 
                  "Background")) {
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_rects(svg))
  }
  if (geom %in% c("GeomArea", "GeomViolin", "GeomSmooth", 
                  "Background")) {
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_areas(svg))
  }
  if (geom %in% c("GeomPoint", "GeomJitter", "GeomDotPlot", 
                  "Background")) {
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_circles(svg))
  }
  if (geom %in% c("GeomLine", "GeomSmooth", "Background")) {
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_lines(svg))
  }
  if (geom %in% c("Background")) {
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_texts(svg))
  }
  if (geom %in% c("GeomSf")) {
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_sf(svg))
  }
  purrr::map(rough_els, ~purrr::list_modify(.x, geom = geom))
}

# Create the function parse_sf.
parse_sf <- function (svg) {
  shape <- "path"
  keys <- NULL
  ggrough:::parse_shape(svg, shape, keys) %>% {
    purrr::map(., 
               ~purrr::list_modify(.x, 
                                   points = .x$d, 
                                   shape = "path"
               ))
  }
}
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)

b <- ggplot(nc) + geom_sf(color = "black") + theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_line(color = NA),  # not resized or removed! (keep spacing)
        axis.text = element_text(color = NA))

options <- list(GeomSf = list(fill_style = "hachure", angle = 60, angle_noise = 1,
                              gap_noise = 0, gap = 6, fill_weight = 2, bowing = 5,
                              roughness = 30))

(xx <- get_rough_chart(b, options))  # from your question
fixer <- function(ggr) {          # where ggr is the ggrough graph
  nd <- lapply(1:length(ggr$x$data), function(j) {
    if(!is.null(ggr$x$data[[j]]$lengthAdjust)) { # if a text element (axis label)
      ggr$x$data[[j]]$content <- ""              # remove text, but keep spacing
      ggr$x$data[[j]]                            # return modified data element
    } else {
      ggr$x$data[[j]]                            # not text, return orig data
    }
  })
  ggr$x$data <- nd                               # add mod data to graph
  ggr                                            # return mod graph
}
xx2 <- xx %>% fixer()  # modify the plot, to hide text

(g2 <- ggplot(nc) +
    geom_sf(fill = "transparent", color = "black", linewidth = 2) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "transparent"), # no white background
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "transparent"),
          text = element_text(size = 9)))      # text size to match defaults in ggrough

gg <- girafe(ggobj = g2, width_svg = 7, height_svg = 5)  # h/w default w/ ggrough

browsable(div( # parent div, size matches ggrough's default
  style = css(width = "960px", height = "500px", position = "relative"),
  div(xx2, style = css(display = "block")),                           # ggrough graph
  div(gg, style = css(position = "absolute", top = 0, padding.top = "54.2px", # layer behind
                      width = "610px", height = "500px", z.index = -2))
              )) # size and padding found by trial and error with defaults for graph sizes



Wow, thanks for doing all of that!!! My I ask two questions? 1) how can I tweak the code to make the borders appear on top of the scribbles? 2) When I run your code exactly, the border layer is exactly the same as yours, but the scribble layer is not in the correct place. I think it is a bit too big, and is to the south and east of the other layer (with lots of overlap). What should I try to modify to get it where it needs to be?

I'm sorry to hear that. That's hard to help with on this end. Of course you can adjust it. It may make it easier to leave the grid (theme elements on the ggrough) so that you can see easier when it's aligned. You can always just comment it out and that remove the comment when they're aligned. If you struggle with getting them aligned you could add it to your question? You could ask another question and let me know (comments send messages...if you didn't already know.)

I asked another question - thanks!
